# Notice: Undefined index: ID in D:\wamp\www\LTID\Updaterlbet.php on line 28

Tags: php, pdo

i have here the code for updating record the problem is that when i try to update a record and hit the submit button it always shows me a error of undefined index..
i hope someone can help me with this,i'm struggling to fix this..

**here are the error:**

> Notice: Undefined index: ID in D:\wamp\www\LTID\Updaterlbet.php on
>   line 28
>   Notice: Undefined index: Province in
>   D:\wamp\www\LTID\Updaterlbet.php on line 31
>   Notice: Undefined index:
>   RLBET_Action in D:\wamp\www\LTID\Updaterlbet.php on line 39 
>   Notice:
>   Undefined index: Month_Approved in D:\wamp\www\LTID\Updaterlbet.php on
>   line 41 
>   Notice: Undefined index: Year_Approved in
>   D:\wamp\www\LTID\Updaterlbet.php on line 42
>   Notice: Undefined index:
>   Summary_of_Reason in D:\wamp\www\LTID\Updaterlbet.php on line 45
>   SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: parameter was not defined

**and here is class.user.php**

```
public function update($ID,$LHID,$LO_Name,$Province,$Municipality,$Barangay,$Title_Number,$Lot_Number,$Survey_Number,$Area,$Resolution_Number,$RLBET_Action,$Resolution_Date,$Month_Approved,$Year_Approved,$PARCCOM_Number,$PARCCOM_Date,$Summary_of_Reason,$Reason_for_Deduction,$Date_Inserted)
  {
    try
    {

    $stmt=$this->db->prepare("UPDATE rlbet SET LHID = :LHID,LO_Name=:LO_Name,Province=:Province, Municipality = :Municipality, Barangay = :Barangay, Title_Number = :Title_Number, Lot_Number = :Lot_Number, Survey_Number = :Survey_Number, Area = :Area, Resolution_Number = :Resolution_Number, Resolution_Date = :Resolution_Date, Month_Approved = :Month_Approved, Year_Approved = :Year_Approved, PARCCOM_Number = :PARCCOM_Number, PARCCOM_Date = :PARCCOM_Date, Summary_of_Reason = :Summary_of_Reason, Reason_for_Deduction = :Reason_for_Deduction, Date_Inserted = NOW() WHERE ID = :ID");

    $stmt->bindparam(":LHID",$LHID);
    $stmt->bindparam(":LO_Name",$LO_Name);
    $stmt->bindparam(":Province",$Province);
    $stmt->bindparam(":Municipality",$Municipality);
    $stmt->bindparam(":Barangay",$Barangay);
    $stmt->bindparam(":Title_Number",$Title_Number);
    $stmt->bindparam(":Lot_Number",$Lot_Number);
    $stmt->bindparam(":Survey_Number",$Survey_Number);
    $stmt->bindparam(":Area",$Area);
    $stmt->bindparam(":Resolution_Number",$Resolution_Number);
    $stmt->bindparam(":RLBET_Action",$RLBET_Action);
    $stmt->bindparam(":Resolution_Date",$Resolution_Date);
    $stmt->bindparam(":Month_Approved",$Month_Approved);
    $stmt->bindparam(":Year_Approved",$Year_Approved);
    $stmt->bindparam(":PARCCOM_Number",$PARCCOM_Number);
    $stmt->bindparam(":PARCCOM_Date",$PARCCOM_Date);
    $stmt->bindparam(":Summary_of_Reason",$Summary_of_Reason);
    $stmt->bindparam(":Reason_for_Deduction",$Reason_for_Deduction);
    $stmt->bindparam(":ID",$ID);
    $stmt->execute();

      return true;
    }
    catch(PDOException $e)
    {
      echo $e->getMessage();
      return false;
    }
  }
```

**Updaterlbet.php**

```
<?php
include_once 'db.php';

$LHID = isset($_GET['LHID']) ? $_GET['LHID'] : '';
$LO_Name = isset($_GET['LO_Name']) ? $_GET['LO_Name'] : '';
$Province = isset($_GET['Province']) ? $_GET['Province'] : '';
$Municipality = isset($_GET['Municipality']) ? $_GET['Municipality'] : '';
$Barangay = isset($_GET['Barangay']) ? $_GET['Barangay'] : '';
$Title_Number = isset($_GET['Title_Number']) ? $_GET['Title_Number'] : '';
$Lot_Number = isset($_GET['Lot_Number']) ? $_GET['Lot_Number'] : '';
$Survey_Number = isset($_GET['Survey_Number']) ? $_GET['Survey_Number'] : '';
$Area = isset($_GET['Area']) ? $_GET['Area'] : '';
$Resolution_Number = isset($_GET['Resolution_Number']) ? $_GET['Resolution_Number'] : '';
$RLBET_Action = isset($_GET['RLBET_Action']) ? $_GET['RLBET_Action'] : '';
$Resolution_Date = isset($_GET['Resolution_Date']) ? $_GET['Resolution_Date'] : '';
$Month_Approved = isset($_GET['Month_Approved']) ? $_GET['Month_Approved'] : '';
$Year_Approved = isset($_GET['Year_Approved']) ? $_GET['Year_Approved'] : '';
$PARCCOM_Number = isset($_GET['PARCCOM_Number']) ? $_GET['PARCCOM_Number'] : '';
$PARCCOM_Date = isset($_GET['PARCCOM_Date']) ? $_GET['PARCCOM_Date'] : '';
$Summary_of_Reason = isset($_GET['Summary_of_Reason']) ? $_GET['Summary_of_Reason'] : '';
$Reason_for_Deduction = isset($_GET['Reason_for_Deduction']) ? $_GET['Reason_for_Deduction'] : '';
$Date_Inserted = isset($_GET['Date_Inserted']) ? $_GET['Date_Inserted'] : '';

if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST")
{
$ID = $_GET['ID'];
$LHID = $_POST['LHID'];
$LO_Name = $_POST['LO_Name'];
$Province = $_POST['Province'];
$Municipality = $_POST['Municipality'];
$Barangay = $_POST['Barangay'];
$Title_Number = $_POST['Title_Number'];
$Lot_Number = $_POST['Lot_Number'];
$Survey_Number = $_POST['Survey_Number'];
$Area = $_POST['Area'];
$Resolution_Number = $_POST['Resolution_Number'];
$RLBET_Action = $_POST['RLBET_Action'];
$Resolution_Date = $_POST['Resolution_Date'];
$Month_Approved = $_POST['Month_Approved'];
$Year_Approved = $_POST['Year_Approved'];
$PARCCOM_Number = $_POST['PARCCOM_Number'];
$PARCCOM_Date = $_POST['PARCCOM_Date'];
$Summary_of_Reason = $_POST['Summary_of_Reason'];
$Reason_for_Deduction = $_POST['Reason_for_Deduction'];
$Date_Inserted = $_POST['Date_Inserted'];

if($LTID->update($ID, $LHID, $LO_Name, $Province, $Municipality, $Barangay, $Title_Number, $Lot_Number, $Survey_Number, $Area, $Resolution_Number, $RLBET_Action, $Resolution_Date, $Month_Approved, $Year_Approved, $PARCCOM_Number, $PARCCOM_Date, $Summary_of_Reason, $Reason_for_Deduction, $Date_Inserted))
{

    echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('Successfully Updated!');</script>";
}
else
{
    echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('Updating Failed!'); </script>";
}
}

if(isset($_GET['ID']))
{
$ID = $_GET['ID'];
extract($LTID->getID($ID));
}
?>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP: "Notice: Undefined variable" and "Notice: Undefined index"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4261133/php-notice-undefined-variable-and-notice-undefined-index)

Comment: @ASR its not duplicate my question is different and i'm struggling with this for a couple of days and i still don't resolved it

Comment: Did you try recommended solutions/answers specified on that question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4261133/php-notice-undefined-variable-and-notice-undefined-index?answertab=active#tab-top

Comment: yes.i already tried it but still not resolved

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure your are using `$_GET` or `$_POST` for `ID`

Try checking all your parameters whether it is set or not like

```
$ID = isset($_GET['ID']) ? $_GET['ID'] : 0 ;
$Province = isset($_POST['Province']) ? $_POST['Province'] : '';
```

This will help you to get rid of the `undefined index` notice.

For `SQLSTATE` error, You bind the `:RLBET_Action` and forgot to add  when you prepare the statement

Hope this will help